# How to draw iOS Safari app-like ticks in Pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

How can I draw a tick in my image on Pixelmator? I'm now creating my iOS app icon with 1,024 x 1,024 pixels, and have put a background rectangle to cover the whole picture, and on it draw a circle and filled it with white. Now want to draw those ticks like in Safari app...

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. Please provide screenshots, it is a little difficult to understand what it is that you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an idea how to create "rotating" icon, since you did not provided any screenshot.

Click on Pen Tool and create by one click a starting point in a desired location (begin at 9 or 3 o'clock of a circle), then press Shift and move the mouse horizontally to the second point of a ray and click again - you will get a horizontal line - the same thing you can create by using Line Shape Tool. If you used a pen - then click escape after creating the second point.

Next, Click on Move tool and select the this line, then press Command+C -> Command+V and RightClick and choose Transform - then rotate the line to 90 degrees. The same you can do by pressing Command+F and entering the exact rotation value on the top of the working area.

Duplicate the line and rotate it to 30 degrees - you need 12 line rotated one by one by 30 degrees, but you need to create only 6 since you just copy every one and place it by mirroring around the center.

The work takes not more than 5 minutes.

updated

If you need more ticks - just move by 15 degrees. Also you can hide inner parts of the ticks by circle colored as a big circle.

1. safari icon pixelmator [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6iinxyriuo38ygq/iOS%207%20Safari%20Icon%20.pxm) - you can just grab things from there.

Comment: What are "ticks"? are we talking about spinners?

Comment: @boblet http://tripletsisters.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/ios-7-safari-icon-pn.png?w=1028&h=1028

Comment: Wow. I do not think I would ever have thought of that.